# Break loop from another class java

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm currently working on somekind text-based 'RPG' game. I made two classes, first one is supposed to simulate road from one town to another and doing so there is a possibility that player will encounter enemy. Fighting logic is placed in another class and when player dies I call method which is supposed to load game from previous save or create new character and that works perfectly fine, but even when player died road is continued instead of breaking loop. LeaveTown class looks like this:

```
public class WorldMap {
boolean running=true;
public void leaveTown(Character character){
    EnemyFactory factory = new EnemyFactory();
    PerformAtack atack = new PerformAtack();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    int progress = 0;
    while(running && progress!=100){
        try {
            System.out.print(sb.append("#"));
            System.out.println(progress+"%");
            if (random.nextDouble() * 10 < 2) {
                atack.performFight(character,factory.generateRandomEnemy());
            }
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }catch(Exception ex){}
        progress = progress+5;
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, I'm using while loop which is supposed to break when running variable is set to false or road is finished. When character dies I call method `battleLost`:

```
 private void battleLost(Character character){
    WorldMap map = new WorldMap();
    System.out.println("You are dead.\nWould you like to try AGAIN or LOAD your last save");
    System.out.println("Please type AGAIN or LOAD");
    while(true) {
        String choice = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        if (choice.equals("AGAIN")) {
            map.running = false;
            System.out.println("Create new character?");
            break;
        } else if (choice.equals("LOAD")) {
            map.running = false;
            save.readFromFile();
            break;
        } else
            System.out.println("Try again.");

    }
}
```

This method sets running variable in class WorldMap to false, but the `while` loop is continued instead of breaking. Im aware that problem is probably linked to using `map.running = false;` in wrong way. 
I'd glad if anyone could explain me how this problem should be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean running=true;
```

This variable should be part of `Character` class.

then, your `while` will just look like:

```
while(character.isRunning() && progress!=100)
```

and, within `performFight` you can update it to `false` when died.

Comment: Thank you, it worked like it was supposed to! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `battleLost()` belongs to `PerformAtack` class. so the local variable `map` inside the `battleLost()` does not affect the object that is controlling the road.

You can do two things:

1. make `running` static (and public) and then you can reference it from anywhere by the class name like this `WolrdMap.runnning = false` but this solution has problems if you decide to do things in parallel (e.g. multiple threads). **Remmeber: static data is almost always a pitfall for multi-threaded design!**
2. a better solution is to make `atack.performFight` return a boolean value and assign that value to the `running` var: `running = atack.performFight(...` this is better design in terms of thread safety, but you will have to propagate the boolean value from `battleLost()` (it too will have to return boolean) to `performFight()' and so on

Comment: I decided to put `boolean running` in Character class and it worked, nevertheless, thank you for your help and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Well,Change the access modifier for variable `boolean running=true;` to `public static boolean running=true;`

once you did that you can change this variable to false without creating an instance in order to break the loop, do something like that

```
private void battleLost(Character character){
WorldMap map = new WorldMap();
System.out.println("You are dead.\nWould you like to try AGAIN or LOAD your last save");
System.out.println("Please type AGAIN or LOAD");
while(WorldMap.running) {
    String choice = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    if (choice.equals("AGAIN")) {
        map.running = false;
        System.out.println("Create new character?");
        break;
    } else if (choice.equals("LOAD")) {
        map.running = false;
        save.readFromFile();
        break;
    } else
        System.out.println("Try again.");

}
public void breakTheLoop(){
WorldMap.running=false;
}
```

because of static is a class variable so it's value will be shared between all classes